# how to show authenticated user data from relations

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to show the data of the authenticated user from his relation with other tables but can't get it to work, and I'm pretty new to laravel.

the user table has a relation with level table thru level_id, and the level table has a morph relation with the languages table, I'm trying to show the language of the level of the current user

here is my user model relation

```
public function level()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Level::class, 'level_id');
    }
```

and my level model

```
public function languages()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Language::class, 'langable');
    }
```

and in the language table, I need to get back the title of 0 or 1 like
languages['0']title.

here is my controller

```
public function profile()
    {
        $user= User::with('level')->with('offers')->get();
        return view('pages.user.index',compact('user'));
    }
```

and here is how I got the auth user

```
 {!! auth()->user()->first_name . ' ' . auth()->user()->last_name !!}
```

I'm trying to get this to work

```
{{auth()->user()->level()->languages()->title['0']}}
```

but it shows me this

[image]

Comment: Try `level()->languages` and if that doesn't help, try `level->languages` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try `{{ $user->level->languages->title['0'] }}` in your index.blade file since you are passing the $user var from your controller to it. Currently you are using the user from session.

Comment: i tried it and i didn't work, even if it were to it'd show all the levels of all the users, right ?

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer guys it goes like this

```
{{Auth::user()->level->languages[0]->title}}
```

that'd show the level of the current user

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there are a few steps you need to get done

1. in your controller:

```php
public function profile()
{
    $user = Auth::user(); // gets the logged in user
    return view('pages.user.profile', compact('user')); // return view with $user variable
}
```

2. in your user model add:

```php
// appends the level data to the $user model
// so every time you retrieve a user, the level data is included and accessible
// after that you can use $user->level in your view file
protected $appends = [
    'level'
];
```

3. in your level model add:

```php
// appends the languages data to the $user model
// so every time you retrieve a level, the languages data is included and accessible
// after that you can use $level->languages in your view file
protected $appends = [
    'languages'
];
```

**NOTE**: In Step 3 you are retrieving multiple languages for a level. Is that correct ?

4. usage in view

```php
$user->level->languages[specificLanguage]->title // if level has multiple languages
$user->level->language->title // if level has one language
```